# Which Mathematics areas do I need to acquaint myself with before studying Lie algebra and representation as a self study undergrad?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am self studying pure mathematics and really need to study Lie groups. I do not have a pure math university background but I have acquainted myself with undergraduate algebra both linear and abstract, as well as real analysis.

Could you please outline for me the mathematical "path" i.e. all the topics I need to be familiar with to understand Lie algebras and representation theory as well as the books I would need (especially Springer books if possible).

A very helpful approach would be to outline as such: Measure theory, Differential geometry, topology... all the undergraduate and graduate topics I would require before pursuing Lie algebra.

Thank you.

Comment: Lie group or Lie algebra?

Comment: Do you have a discount deal with Springer? If not (and actually, even, if so), then I think you should focus on the quality of the book and not its publisher.

Comment: Lie algebra representations can be studied from a purely algebraic viewpoint, but for Lie groups, some familiarity with smooth manifolds is quite useful.

Comment: To me, the importance of Lie algebras arises originally from the study of Lie groups. And, with both, it's best to study concrete examples, namely the standard matrix ones. So I would recommend starting with Stillwell's book Naive Lie Theory. It's nice an concrete and lays a nice foundation for the more abstract advanced theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can study Lie algebras without Lie groups, and for this you only really need to know linear algebra. Having some understanding of basic abstract algebra and group theory also helps for understanding the basic techniques and ideas.

A friendly introduction to Lie algebras is in Erdmann and Wildon, "Introduction to Lie Algebras". They do not discuss Lie groups at all. But they will teach you about Lie algebras and root systems, which are essential for Lie theory.

More advanced introduction to Lie algebras is the classic book by J. E. Humphreys, which also does not talk about Lie groups. But it contains all the essentials of complex semisimple Lie algebras and their representation theory.

For Lie groups, you could look at "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction" by Brian C. Hall.

Comment: Because "know linear algebra" can mean different things to different people, I would just add to this very good answer that in my view, one needs a solid understanding of linear maps up to and including Jordan normal form, characteristic and minimal polynomial, determinant and trace, and how all those are interrelated; also, a good understanding of bilinear forms up to and including Sylvester's law of inertia is tremendously helpful. While the goal of the theory is to do things almost without matrix computations, it is a good thing to brace oneself to use matrix computations a lot in examples.

Comment: I also agree that these are very good book suggestions. Let me just add that my colleague Walter Mazorchuk has an 18-videos series about Lie algebras on youtube: https://youtu.be/q77hAZQ0zTw in case videos are helpful to you as well.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Thanks for this comment, since I didn't clarify how much linear algebra exactly in my answer. In any case as you say understanding diagonalizability, Jordan normal form, characteristic polynomials, etc. is very helpful. I guess for a student who is motivated to learn about Lie algebras, one doesn't need a perfect/complete knowledge of all this linear algebra --- applying it to Lie algebras should be a good motivation.